# Building Multiple directory structures with Vite

Tags: vite

Given the following directory structure, I'm attempting to generate a `./dist` directory with ViteJS, using the `./src/apps/` directory as modules to build.

```
/dist
   /appA
      - index.js
      - index.css
      /media
      - image.png
/src
   /apps
      /appA
         /css
           a.css
           b.css
         /js
           a.js
           b.js
         /media
           image.png
         index.html
```

This almost does what I expect it to do, as it moves `src/apps/appA/js/index.js` to `dist/appA/index.js`.
vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig( {
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                appA: path.resolve( __dirname, 'src/apps/appA/index.html' ),
            },
            output: {
                entryFileNames: '[name]/index.js',
                dir: 'dist',
            },
        },
        emptyOutDir: true,
    }
} );
```

however, the `index.html` and `a.css` do not go to expected directories. `index.html` goes to `dist/src/apps/appA/index.html` and `a.css` goes to `dist/assets/a-[hash].css`

I've attempted to change this by setting `output.assetFileNames` to a function. Unfortunately, the css asset doesn't provide a filepath in the `assetInfo` object, so I cannot discern the appropriate directory to stick the file.

I know there is likely a better and much simpler way of doing this. However, I cannot figure it out for the life of me.